# Bash Read Stdin from Given PID

Tags: linux, bash, stdin, pid

I have a question regarding Linux in general, though an answer for Bash would be optimal. How would one read the stdin/stdout/stderr of a given process (by PID) from a script? In other words, how can I get the stdin/stdout/stderr of another program from a script? I have as yet been unable to find any answers online elsewhere.

So far, I have been able to find the process id

```
pidof {some-process-name}
```

And then find the location of its stdin socket (I think that's what it's called...)

```
readlink -f /proc/{PID}/fd/0
```

Which usually produces something like

```
/dev/pts/1
```

Then I am able to write to that stdin

```
echo "Hello World" > /dev/pts/1
```

However attempting to read from either that socket

```
cat /dev/pts/1
```

Or from the original file

```
cat /proc/{PID}/fd/0
```

Both produce nothing, simply waiting indefinitely, even after the process is terminated, and thus the file deleted.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
Found a way to solve the problem, see my answer below.

Comment: If you want to read stdout of a process with pid 1234, try: `strace -p 1234 -s 1000 -e write`.

Comment: Is the process a subprocess? If it is, then you can set up stdin/out/err redirection when you create the subprocess.

Comment: Regrettably it is not a subprocess, I need to be able to do what I described with any already-running processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interact with a program's file descriptors after it has been started. The entries in `/proc/$pid/fd/` simply tell you where the file descriptors are connected -- you can write to the place which is connected to stdout, and find out where it's reading its stdin from, but not change what they are connected to or inject new data into any of those streams.

A common workaround for this is to run the program under a tool which enables these operations (`expect`, `tmux`, etc) but of course that needs to happen at the time you start the program.

Comment: So there's definitely no way you know to do it?

Comment: No simple straightforward way that I know of. Certainly somebody could write a kernel module to allow some sort of root override on the syscall level, but given that workarounds exist, and quick googling returns nothing, my impression is that nobody has done that.

Comment: Googling for "inject stdin to running process" returns a large number of vaguely promising results, but all the ones I looked at are either wrong or another duplicate of this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: I think I'll wait to see if anyone else comes up with anything, if not, then I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after about a day of experimenting, I managed to do it. A read stream works on either `/proc/{PID}/fd/0` or whatever that file links to (found with readlink as stated in my question). The readstream yields a result every time something is typed into the stdin of the program. For my tests, it seems to only work for the keyboard, not for keystrokes roughly simulated with `echo "Hello World" > /dev/pts/1` Nonetheless, it is sufficient for my purposes. Thank you to all others for pointing me in the right direction!